# Executing Simple Unix Terminal Commands using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, unix, terminal, command

I am trying to execute simple terminal commands through Node.js but so far have only gotten 'ls' to work.. What if I want to change directory etc? Anyone know how to do that?
 Here is code that just does the 'ls' command via Node.js.

```
 var exec = require('child_process').exec;
 var cmd = 'ls';
 exec(cmd,function(error,stdout,stderr){

      console.log(stdout);
      console.log(stderr);
      if(error!=null){
            console.log(error);
        }
   });
```

Comment: Things like "cd" aren't commands, they are capabilities of the shell e.g. bash.  Each command you run as above is run as its own process with its own environment, so if you are trying to emulate a shell you will have to build that state tracking on your own.

Answer (score 2):

Well I'm using a command abtrations for doing thing like that.. You can practically use the `cd` like in your terminal whit this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs

how to use a `cd`:

```
var shell = require('shelljs');
shell.cd('../');
```

and the good thing It's that is an abstraction to the command so It should work on any OS..

Answer (score -2):

First : Try to get the input data from your console
Second : Try to execute it in the node code
Third : Try to get the result and show it in your console

All those steps, you can get the answer from google or docs of nodejs. If you can't find the answer, try to search it in npm.

Comment: the first step you can try to use readline(lib) ,second you can use child_process as you tried before.